# Tire (Elastic Search) Nil Comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

For Tire (ElasticSearch wrapper gem), how do you query and filter out indexed records that has nil/null value for a certain attribute. For example, if I have this relationship

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

I have article indexed but I want to avoid pulling back records with **topic_id = nil**. I tried this code blow but it didn't work.

```
class Article
  belongs_to :topic

  def search(q)
    tire.search do
       ...
         filter :missing, :field => :topic_id, { :existence => false, :null_value => false }
         ...
         ### filter :range, :topic_id => { :gt => 0 } # ==> I tried this as well but didn't work
       ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [exists filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/exists-filter.html) if you want to filter only documents with existing `topic_id` value.

```
class Article
  belongs_to :topic

  def search(q)
     tire.search do
       ...
       filter :exists, :field => :topic_id
       ...
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can use [query string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html) with `_exists_:topic_id` query.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
class Article
  belongs_to :topic

  def search(q)
    tire.search do
         ...
         filter :not, :missing => {:field => :topic_id, { :null_value => true } }
         ...
    end
  end
end
```

This should work. existence is required if you want to check if the field exists or not. I guess you just need the null_value check.

Comment: You cannot set both null_value and existence to false. Atleast one or both should be set to true.

Answer (score -3):

@articles = Article.where('topic_id is not ?' , nil)

Comment: Sorry but this is for the Tire gem DSL (ElasticSearch wrapper). Not ActiveRecord.